# Windows 8 app and nodejs websocket not connecting to each other

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, websocket, windows

I'm working with a windows app and trying to connect it to node server.
I'm using web sockets in the windows app and and 'websocket' from npm for node.
I'm have trouble connecting the two it seems like there connecting but when I try to send information across(simple hello world string) nothing happens.
I have a simple javascript windows app.
In my default.html there is just a simple button:

```
 <button onclick="Check()">Check status</button>
```

In the default.js I have the Check function which is:

```
function Check()
{
    var host = "ws://192.168.201.91:8080";
    try
    {
        socket = new WebSocket(host);
        socket.onopen = function (openEvent)
        {
            console.log("Sockets open");
            socket.send("Hello, world");
            console.log("Socket state: " + socket.readyState);
            console.log("Message is sent to: " + socket.url);
        };
        socket.onerror = function (errorEvent)
        {
            console.log(" 'WebSocket Status:: Error was reported';")
        };
        socket.onclose = function (closeEvent)
        {
                 console.log("WebSocket Status:: Socket Closed");
        };
        socket.onmessage = function (messageEvent)
        {
            console.log(socket.toString);
            var received_msg = messageEvent.data;
            console.log("Message recieved: " + received_msg);
        }
    }
    catch(exception)
    {
        if (window.console)
            console.log(exception);
    }
}
```

socket.readyState return me 1 which states a connection is made and the socket is ready for sending!
My node server then looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
var WebSocketServer = require('websocket').server;
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    console.log((new Date()) + ' Received request for ' + request.url);
    response.writeHead(404);
    response.end();
});
server.listen(8080, function() {
    console.log((new Date()) + ' Server is listening on port 8080');
});

wsServer = new WebSocketServer({
    httpServer: server,

    // You should not use autoAcceptConnections for production
    // applications, as it defeats all standard cross-origin protection
    // facilities built into the protocol and the browser.  You should
    // *always* verify the connection's origin and decide whether or not
    // to accept it.
    autoAcceptConnections: true
});
console.log("Here wsServer");
function originIsAllowed(origin) {
  // put logic here to detect whether the specified origin is allowed.
  return true;
}

wsServer.on('request', function(request) {
    //if (!originIsAllowed(request.origin)) {
     // Make sure we only accept requests from an allowed origin
      //request.reject();
     //  console.log((new Date()) + ' Connection from origin ' + request.origin + ' rejected.');
     //  return;
    //}
    console.log("Here");
    var connection = request.accept('echo-protocol', request.origin);
    console.log((new Date()) + ' Connection accepted.');
    connection.on('message', function(message) {
        if (message.type === 'utf8') {
            console.log('Received Message: ' + message.utf8Data);
            connection.sendUTF(message.utf8Data);
        }

    });
    connection.on('close', function(reasonCode, description) {
        console.log((new Date()) + ' Peer ' + connection.remoteAddress + ' disconnected.');
    });
});
```

I have taken out any security checks as I just want the message to send to the server.
But this is not happening and I dont know why! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit --
Just thought it should be possible to send information to see if it hits the sever but i am just not sure on a windows app what the ip is! If I can tell my node server to send information that will at least let me know that a channel is open.
Any ideas how to get the ip of a windows app through javascript?